How to step back debugging in PhpStorm?
I am searching for an option to step back debug in PhpStorm using Xdebug. Where is this option?
Thx in advanced for every constructive help! Here is method, which will be called from anywhere

I want to know code, which is calling upper method. Here are PhpStorm debug options:

I tried to find symbols, but I didn't succeed.

"step back"? As in "move execution point back, to the previously executed line"? There is no such stuff in Xdebug. But your 2nd screenshots shows what you need -- the stack trace (on the left side, where it says AuthController.php:39 etc. -- you can click on previous stacks there (e.g. HttpKernel.php: 181) and it will take you to the calling place. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/navigating-from-stacktrace-to-source-code.html

@LazyOne You should probably post it as the answer?

"step back"? As in, "move execution point back, to the previously executed line"? There is no such stuff in Xdebug.
There was Dontbug Debugger project like 8 or so years ago, that could allow going backwards, but it was an experiment only.

Your 2nd screenshots show what you need -- the Stack Trace (on the left side). By default, it has the current frame selected -- the line where it says AuthController.php:39.

You can click on previous stacks there (e.g. HttpKernel.php:181) and it will take you to the calling place in the editor as well as show the variables and their values for that place.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/navigating-from-stacktrace-to-source-code.html

Related: PhpStorm take a step back in debugger
